# I need to Add a new Build(Working Fine) and update(doesn't update) an Old build at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

//Exception: The instance of entity type 'Citbuild' cannot be tracked because another instance //with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, //ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using //'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."}

```
            foreach (var buildData in builds)
            {
                //make old build to Archive
                buildData.BuildStatus = (long)BuildStatus.Archive;
           
                NewBuildDto newBuild = new NewBuildDto();
                newBuild = GetCopyNewBuildRecord(buildData);
                newBuild.BuildStatus = (long)BuildStatus.Requested;
                newBuild.DeliveryStatus = null;
                newBuild.RequestDate = DateTime.Now;
                newBuild.DeliveredDate = null;
                newBuild.ReworkId = reworkId;
                newBuild.CreatedDate = newBuild.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                newBuild.CreatedBy = newBuild.ModifiedBy = currentUser;
                newBuild.BuildId = newBuildId;
                newBuild.LinkFile = null;
                newBuild.Cpsfile = null;
                newBuild.Csvlink = newBuildId;
                newBuild.FileName = null;
                newBuild.FtpserverId = null;
                var newCitBuild = newBuild.ToDataEntity();
                _context.Citbuilds.Add(newCitBuild);
                _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The newCitBuild is working fine BUT buildData.BuildStatus = (long)BuildStatus.Archive; is not getting updated,

Comment: Two questions: 1. Cna you update your question with the code for `GetCopyNewBuildRecord`? and 2. Which property is the primary key for your `Citbuilds` table?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.